# Stop video after exiting fullscreen on Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, events, mobile-safari, fullscreen

Hey Guys,
I've got a thumbnail on a webpage that when clicked, plays a video in fullscreen using the webkitEnterFullscreen() method.

But I need the video to stop playing once the users touches the "Done" button and leaves fullscreen mode.

Is there an event that fires once the the user has exited fullscreen?

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: how does it not stop playing when user touches done? its playing in the background? I know this question is very old, but I'm just curious if you remember. maybe you meant you need to hide the video, and show the thumbnail again which is what my requirement is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had an email from an Apple developer which answered this question for me.

> The two events are webkitbeginfullscreen and webkitendfullscreen.  This piece of sample code is really useful for seeing the order that events fire (it logs a message to the page whenever an event is emitted), and includes these two events:
>
> http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#samplecode/HTML5VideoEventFlow/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010085-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2